# document.getElementById only works once

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to have an HTML Select box control what is being displayed on the screen without having to refresh the entire page.  I have reduced this down to it's most simple form for debugging and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  On the first load it works.  When a selection is made .ajax works fine but the document.getElementById().innerHTML won't update the screen after that first time.  Html and JS are not my first languages so any advice will help.  TIA

This is from my actual php file.

```
<?php

function getSelectionInfo($id)
{
  switch ($id) {
    case '1'  :
        $selectioninfo = "Title #1";            break;
    case '2'  :
        $selectioninfo = "Title #2";            break;    
    case '3'  :
        $selectioninfo = "Title #3";            break;
    case '4'  :
        $selectioninfo = "Title #4";            break;
    case '5'  :
        $selectioninfo = "Title #5";            break;
    }

echo <<<_END
    <script>
      document.getElementById('selectioninfo').innerHTML = "$selectioninfo";
    </script>
_END;

  return;
}

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $id  = $_POST['id'];
}
else {
  $id  = 2;
}

echo <<<_END
<script src = 'js/jquery.min.js'></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select name = 'selectionbox' id = 'selectionbox' size = 5
        onChange = "loadSelection(this.value);">
_END;
      for ($J = 1; ($J <= 5); ++$J) {
          $recid  = $J;
          $title  = 'Selection ' . $J;

          echo $recid == 2?
          "<option selected = 'selected' value = '$recid'> $title 
          </option>":
          "<option value = '$recid'> $title 
          </option>";
        }
echo <<<_END
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id = 'selectioninfo' >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

_END;

  getSelectionInfo($id);

echo <<<_END

<script>
function loadSelection(val)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    data: {"id": val},
  });
}
</script>

_END;
```

This is what I copied from the screen rendering.

```
  </head><body>
    <div>
      <select name="selectionbox" id="selectionbox" size="5" onchange="loadSelection(this.value);"><option value="1"> Selection 1 
          </option><option selected="selected" value="2"> Selection 2 
          </option><option value="3"> Selection 3 
          </option><option value="4"> Selection 4 
          </option><option value="5"> Selection 5 
          </option>      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="selectioninfo">Title #2</div>
  

    <script>
      document.getElementById('selectioninfo').innerHTML = "Title #2";
    </script>
<script>
function loadSelection(val)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    data: {"id": val},
  });
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It might be easier to help you if, rather than posting the PHP, you show us what the rendered HTML shows up as in the browser

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear.  I attached a screen shot to the original post.  Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Include the code (as text) within your posts.

Comment: That's what I did.  And then the person wanted to see the html output.  It's right there.  Don't you see it?

Comment: We'd like the rendered html as text, not as an image.

Comment: As an old Cobol/RPG programmer apparently I don't know what you are asking me for.

Comment: Copy the HTML from your screenshot in to the question as text, not an image.

Comment: Ok.  Took me a moment to figure out how to copy the html from that screen through 'inspect' but hopefully this is what you guys are asking me for.  Sorry for being so dense.  I started doing this when we weren't dealing with browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 </head><body>
    <div>
      <select name="selectionbox" id="selectionbox" size="5" onchange="loadSelection(this.value);"><option value="1"> Selection 1 
          </option><option selected="selected" value="2"> Selection 2 
          </option><option value="3"> Selection 3 
          </option><option value="4"> Selection 4 
          </option><option value="5"> Selection 5 
          </option></select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="selectioninfo">Title #2</div>
    
        <button onclick="handleClick()" id="clickMeButton">Click here </button>


    <script>
            function handleClick() {
                document.getElementById('selectioninfo').innerHTML = "Title #33";
            }               
    </script>

</body>
```

Add some sort of event, this is an example of a button changing the HTML.

Comment: There is an 'onChange' event in the html select.  That calls a js function that has an ajax (jquery) function passing the value back to the server.  In debug I can see the server getting the new value and I pull data based on that.  I try to update the screen using document.getElementById().innerHTML and it only works the first time.  After that it doesn't update the data in that div.  I've moved around some of this code to see if I have something in the wrong order but no luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).